# Maven 2 & Packaging ejb vs jar

Tags: java, maven-2, ejb-3.1

If i'm working with ejb 3.1, what's the différence between

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

and

```
<packaging>ejb</packaging>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned at http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/usage.html ,

"The plugin doesn't do any EJB specific processing during the generation of the jar except for validating the existence of an EJB deployment descriptor if the EJB version is 2.0+ "

Since you have ejb 3.1 the ejb-jar.xml file is optional hence unless you want to generate client stubs and utility classes as mentioned  in Martin' comments  , it won't make much a difference if you use jar packaging  .

Answer (score 7):

Using packaging type `ejb` includes the execution of the [maven-ejb-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/usage.html). This is not the case for packaging type `jar` (unless you explicitly configure it). The plugin configuration as stated in the original question is only required if you need to define a configuration that differs from defaults.

To my knowledge the main purpose of the maven-ejb-plugin is (was) for creating an [EJB client](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/examples/generating-ejb-client.html) module (only including interfaces). But IMHO this is no longer the recommended way. Usually you provide the APIs via a separate module and do not let the ejb-plugin create it automatically.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  So the ejb packaging is not really usefull anymore.

Comment: The resulting JAR will probably be pretty much the same but it's still correct to use the packaging type 'ejb'. And as jay stated, it verifies the existence of the EJB deployment descriptor.

Answer (score 3):

I would also suggest comparing effective pom outputs from maven help plugin for both `jar` and `ejb` project types:

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

It will allow to compare what maven generates for `ejb` projects and for `jar` projects.

The difference between `ejb` and `jar` also makes sence when packaging into ear plugin. As a rule, `ejbModule` configuration property is used for ejb-jars, containing beans, while `jarModule` configuration property of the ear plugin is used for libraries (jar archives).